# How should I loop through this JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

Here is my code I want to print out "song" property from data. Link to JSON is -> http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';

    request.send();

    request.onload = function(){
        var myjsondata = request.response;
        showdata(myjsondata);
    } 

    function showdata(data){
        var song_name = data;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            document.write(song_name);
            document.write("<br>");

        }
    }

</script>
```

When I run it in browser I get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] as OUTPUT or undefined.

Comment: You cant print object directly on browser you need to parse that.

Comment: No need to use parse @NitinDhomse I got the answer thanks for your reply you can check Jonas answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data looks like this:

```
[  //the array in data
{  //the first object, e. g. data[0]
  "song":"Afreen Afreen", // song => data[0].song
  "url":"http://hck.re/Rh8KTk",
  "artists":"Rahat Fateh Ali Khan, Momina Mustehsan",
  "cover_image":"http://hck.re/kWWxUI"
},
{  
  "song":"Aik Alif",
  "url":"http://hck.re/ZeSJFd",
  "artists":"Saieen Zahoor, Noori",
  "cover_image":"http://hck.re/3Cm0IX"
},
{  
  "song":"Tajdar e haram",
  "url":"http://hck.re/wxlUcX",
  "artists":"Atif Aslam",
  "cover_image":"http://hck.re/5dh4D5"
}]
```

So to loop over one can do

```
var limit=Math.max(data.length,100);//max displayed number

for(var i=0;i<limit;i++){
 document.write(data[i].song+"<br>");
}
```

Whole code:

```js
    document.write("loading...");

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {        
        var data= JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        var limit=Math.max(data.length,100);
        for(var i=0;i<limit;i++){
         document.write(data[i].song+"<br>");
        }
      }
    };
    
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio', true);
    xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas w you made my day.

Comment: but when I run it in mozilla the webpage keeps on loading how to stop that should I use break statement? but where? @Jonas w

Comment: @rock stone so you want to limit the results?

Comment: I want to display all 9 song in JSON file so after all song are printed on screen it should stop loading but it doesn't stop @Jonas w

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write the whole song object to the document. You should map it first:

```
var songNames = data.map(function(item) { return item.song; });
```

This will give you an array of all the names (strings), which you can write to the document:

```
songNames.forEach(function(songName) {
    document.write(songName + '<br>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `JSON.stringify`; and if you plan to write to document I suggest wrapping in `pre` tags as well to retain string format.

```js
let data = [  
  {  
    "song":"Afreen Afreen",
    "url":"http://hck.re/Rh8KTk",
    "artists":"Rahat Fateh Ali Khan, Momina Mustehsan",
    "cover_image":"http://hck.re/kWWxUI"
  },
  {  
    "song":"Aik Alif",
    "url":"http://hck.re/ZeSJFd",
    "artists":"Saieen Zahoor, Noori",
    "cover_image":"http://hck.re/3Cm0IX"
  },
  {  
    "song":"Tajdar e haram",
    "url":"http://hck.re/wxlUcX",
    "artists":"Atif Aslam",
    "cover_image":"http://hck.re/5dh4D5"
  }
];

document.write('<pre>'+ JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t') + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to stringify the object to make it readable.

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var requestURL = 'http://starlord.hackerearth.com/sureify/cokestudio';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET', requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';

    request.send();

    request.onload = function(){
        var myjsondata = request.response;
        showdata(myjsondata);
    } 

    function showdata(data){
        var song_name = data;

        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            document.write(JSON.stringify(song_name));
            document.write("<br>");

        }
    }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from the request is an array of json objects and you are just trying to write the return object over and over again. You need to iterate over the returned data and output each object's value. Change your showdata function as:

```
function showdata(data){


        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

            document.write(data[i].song);
            document.write("<br>");

        }
    }
```